# logarithm answer not accurate

Tags: java

```
//Count the number of documents available

 File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\fypworkspace\\TextRenderer");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    int numDoc = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        if ((listOfFiles[i].getName().endsWith(".txt"))) {
            numDoc++;
        }
    }

//Count the number of documents containing a string

System.out.println("Please enter the required word  :");
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word2 = scan2.nextLine();
    String[] array2 = word2.split(" ");

    for (int b = 0; b < array2.length; b++) {
        int numofDoc = 0;



        for (int i = 0; i < filename; i++) {

            try {

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                        "C:\\Users\\user\\fypworkspace\\TextRenderer\\abc"
                                + i + ".txt"));

                int matchedWord = 0;

                Scanner s2 = new Scanner(in);

                {

                    while (s2.hasNext()) {
                        if (s2.next().equals(array2[b]))
                            matchedWord++;
                    }

                }
                if (matchedWord > 0)
                    numofDoc++;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("File not found.");
            }

        }
        System.out.println(array2[b] + " --> This number of files that contain the term  " +  numofDoc);
        double inverseTF = Math.log ( numDoc/ numofDoc );
        System.out.println(array2[b] + " --> This inverse term frequency that contain the term  " +  inverseTF);
    }

}
}
```

When i trying to calculate the inverseTF where the formula is

log(numDoc / numofDoc),

I do not get the right answer.

Anyone got ideas ?

The output of the program is

```
The number of files available is 11.
is --> This number of files that contain the term is  7
is --> This inverse term frequency that contain the term  0.45198510206864073
```

Comment: Could you post a print of program execution?

Comment: hi, i already updated my question. Thanks for you attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Math.log()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log%28double%29) is the log in base `e`, maybe you're looking for [Math.log10()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log10%28double%29). But since you're not giving any information about what is the expected result and what is wrong, I can't say for sure.

There's also possible that you have a rounding error because your two variables are `int`. Try :

```
Math.log ((float) numDoc / numofDoc);
```

Comment: hi, i already updated my question. Thanks for your attention. It is not accurate. I wonder where is my mistake is. :(

Comment: Why cast to `float` instead of `double`?  I thought the only real reasons to use a float instead of a double were when memory was an issue?

Comment: @Michael Both numbers are int, so casting in a float or a double won't change a thing, we must only signify to Java that we don't want an integer division. But maybe casting to a double will be faster since log() takes a double. It's worth benchmarking ;)

Comment: Well not that it's a big deal, but in general the quotient won't be representable exactly as a floating-point number.  As such I would expect a loss of precision by casting as a float, dividing, casting to a double, and taking the log as compared to just doing the original as a cast to double (though I haven't checked this so I could be wrong).  Of course even if there is a difference it would be very minor.

Answer (score 3):

Since numDoc and numOfDoc are ints, you are using integer division. Try casting them both to double, like so:

```
double inverseTF = Math.log ( (double)numDoc / (double)numofDoc );
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do `numDoc/numOfDock`, since the variables are typed `int`, it will do an integer division, and then cast the result to a `double` for the  `Math.log` call, which will then yield an approximate result for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to use integer division, so you probably want to be taking the log of `((double)numDoc)/numofDoc`.  Furthermore, it looks like you probably want the [base 10 logarithm](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log10%28double%29)
, but `Math.log` in Java is the base e or [natural logarithm](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log%28double%29):.